# How to use autofill on multiple login fields on a website

Tags: html, forms, browser, passwords, autofill

When having two separate login fields on a webpage, my browser (Google Chrome) assumes that both of them require the same credentials, which is not a valid assumption. I would have liked my browser to store the credentials to each of them separately.

```
<form id='login-form' method = "post" action = "/login.html">
    <ul>
        <li><input id = "username" name = "username" type = "text" placeholder = "Username"/></li>
        <li><input id = "password" name = "password" type = "password" placeholder = "Password"/></li>
        <li><input id = "button" type = "submit" value = "Login"/></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

On another HTML page:

```
<form id='dx-login-form' method = "post" action = "/dxLogin">
    <ul>
        <li><input id = "dx_username" name = "dx_username" type = "text" placeholder = "Username"/></li>
        <li><input id = "dx_password" name = "dx_password" type = "password" placeholder = "Password"/></li>
        <li><input id = "button" type = "submit" value = "Login"/></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give the second login form different autocomplete identifiers so it won't auto-fill from the first login form.

```
    <li><input id = "dx_username" name = "dx_username" type = "text" placeholder = "Username" autocomplete = "dx_username" /></li>
    <li><input id = "dx_password" name = "dx_password" type = "password" placeholder = "Password" autocomplete = "dx_password" /></li>
```

For more info: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill

Comment: It doesn't work. When I log into the main login, chrome asks if I prefer it to remember the login credentials. I say yes, and when I get to the second login form the credentials I just entered on the first form are autocompleted. When logging in to the second form, Chrome again asks if it should store the password. I say yes, and when I enter the first form again, the credentials form the second form are suggested.

Comment: it is not enough just separate `autocomplete` does not work for password chrome manager