# Few different login forms on one domain - diffrent passwords from browser

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

I have two login forms. Each of them enables logging in into diffrent account. These accounts can use the same email and other passwords. That creates a problem with suggesting wrong password.

I would like to know if there is some kind of possibility to associate 'account in browser password manager' with one from several login forms within one domain? Is there any possibility to have two accounts with the same e-mail and diffrent password? One would be prompt as a suggest only in first login form, ale the other only in the second login form?

Comment: You could just disable autofill and create your own prompts

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use a username instead of the email address to login in with and have the email link to the unique username name of which multiple accounts can have the same email address. If I understood you correctly. but try making the question clearer.

what you can do is add the following

```html
<form>
<input id = "f1_username" name="username" />
<input id = "f1_password" name="password" type="password" />
</form>

<form>
<input id = "f2_username" name="username" />
<input id = "f2_password" name="password" type="password" />
</form>
```

you can try some thing like that.
the answer on this post can help [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382827/how-to-use-autofill-on-multiple-login-fields-on-a-website)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to make it easier to understand.

Comment: User can add his user login data to browser password manager, I would like to prompt his data as a suggestion depending on the form he is using. 
So in one form where he enetered data I want to display browser suggestions  but I don't want to show it in the other form (where his data are completely different) to not confuse the user.

Comment: This may help you with what you want.